# Kombucha as a vitamin B12 source

Tags: veganism, b12

Kombucha can have very high amounts of vitamin B12 (e.g. https://www.reddit.com/r/mildlyinteresting/comments/65wjep/this_kombucha_has_a_ridiculous_amount_of_b12/).

Where does the vitamin B12 come from? From which process?

When I make my own Kombucha, how can I tune the amount of B12? Which ingredients should be in there / to what should I pay attention?

Comment: Please see [my answer here](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/a/267/74) on sources of B12 - consuming kombucha may not reliably prevent B12 deficiency

Comment: You're looking for 'cyanobacteria', how effective it'll be in your brewery can't say.